# How to list all nodes of nodetype A which has the current node referenced?

Tags: nodes, views

So this is what I'm trying to do in Drupal 6:

Node type A is video, node type B is a person
Nodetype A has a reference field where you can enter a reference to any Node from nodetype B

how can I create a block view which will be displayed on nodes from node type b, which will show all the nodes from node type A where the current node from node type B is referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to make references two-way. To do this, use:

- [Corresponding Entity References](https://drupal.org/project/cer) for Drupal 7
- [Corresponding node references](https://drupal.org/project/cnr) for Drupal 6

That way, current node will reference all nodes that reference it - and from this point creating a [view](https://drupal.org/project/views) is trivial - or **you can simply display the field** created for back reference, *without need for a views module at all*.

**Other way is to use Views**. Create a view displaying nodes from content type A, add argument *content reference field > provide default argument > node ID from URL* and display this block view on the nodes from content type B.

Comment: This does work, but I am pretty sure CNR requires each content type to have a noderef field on it, which it then keeps in sync.

Comment: @MPD yes, it does. But the field only needs to be there, it does not need to be displayed. And the fact it's just a normal field from the point of view of other modules makes it so easy to work with, ie to use Views on it.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like I would need to create new nodes for Corresponding node reference to work.  I already have plenty of nodes from nodetype A which reference nodes frome nodetype B, so I would prefer a solution where I could create a view based on the existing references

Comment: @LieutenantMcClane not new nodes, just new non-displayed field on existing ones. But I understand you prefer to avoid that. The point is, at least for Entity Reference [feature request for this functionality](https://drupal.org/node/1293792) was [closed in favour of Corresponding Entity References](https://drupal.org/node/1293792#comment-6158534)... It does not mean it's impossible to go another way, of course.

Comment: @MPD in addition to my comment above you wasn't notified about, I wanted to ask how can you imagine going without another field? Full scan of all nodes each time list is refreshed? Everything else seems to require some storage for "the other way" and I don't see how a field on the other end is worse than any of the alternatives. (My question is not rhetoric one, I would really like to know, maybe I'm missing something).

Comment: @Mołot I am prety sure you configure a view over the one type, and add a contentual filter to it to pull in the nid of the node being viewed.  I just need to think of a project where I did it to double check the view settings.

Comment: @MPD I don't think that it would be simpler to implement than simply allowing that "backward" reference to be shown, and theming it like any other field. But of course it will be a perfectly valid alternative. By the way, answer slightly updated.

Comment: I'm not sure, have a look at this module https://drupal.org/project/backreference

Comment: @Bala works just like CNR and also requires fields at both ends.

Comment: I achieved it without adding more fields and using CNR. I simply created a view displaying nodes from nodetype a, added argument content  refence field >provide default argument> node id from url and displayed this block view on the nodes from nodetype b

Comment: @LieutenantMcClane And good. You know you can answer your own question, too?

Comment: @Molot I edited my comment to provide the description of what I did

Comment: @LieutenantMcClane you should post that as actual answer, not as a comment that may be deleted wuthout notice.