# Views show referencing nodes

Tags: views, nodes

I have a custom content type called "questions" and few others , "A", "B","C" . (the naming is irrelevant, actually).
Each one of the following content types "A","B","C" has a field that is referencing to a particular node with content type "question".

What I would like to do is to display in a View all questions and next to each question, the titles of referencing nodes(with links to the node).

What approach should be taken ?

Comment: Is this different from [How to list all nodes of nodetype A which has the current node referenced?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/88356/16495)

Comment: Hi, 

I think its different, since we do not have the contextual filter.

Comment: I was asking about a problem, not a solution. If your problem is not different, you can add a filter ;) But maybe I'm simply not understanding you here - if so, please clarify a bit. My language skill is not that great, sorry, but maybe if I'll understand, I'll be able to help.

Comment: In general its the same nature problem, just a bit different usecase. A bit later I will update. I have been temporary reassigned to another issue. 
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following.

1. Add the title node with link.
2. Filter it with Content Type A B and C (Which all content types you want to display.
3. Add the reference field in Content Type A B and C
4. Group by the Reference Field.

Comment: I see !.. I will give it a try and let you know a bit later.
Regards