# I want to display one content type inside of another

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a page called "Our Team" that will display all the members of our team. I have a content type called "Team Member" and have created many team members under this content type. How can I list all "Team Members" on one page?

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/views

Comment: + https://drupal.org/project/entityreference :)

Comment: Actually @kalabro pointed to more convenient way :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all nodes of nodetype A which has the current node referenced?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88356/how-to-list-all-nodes-of-nodetype-a-which-has-the-current-node-referenced)

Comment: @Mołot A whole new content type and an entity reference field, just to show one page with a list of content, which is what Views does out of the box? Really?! Either my friday Guinness is clouding my judgement, or that seems like a rather backwards way of doing things. To my mind you just delete the "Our Team" content type, which is redundant, and create a new View showing nodes of "Team Member" type.

Comment: @Clive maybe I'm wrong, but the very title of a post suggest there **already are** two content types, so no, **I am not suggesting any new content type**. Only one field. One field vs one view? Well, field seems way easier to configure to me, as CER module is created exactly to solve this use case and views are universal, so needs tailoring to specific use case. By the way, Жигулёвское is surprisingly OK, too ;)

Comment: @Mołot I hadn't really thought about it like that, I see your point. Whatever language that is it hurts my head by the way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is the combination of the comments above.

1. To your team 'Team member' content type add [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field with reference to 'Our Team' content type
2. Create a [view](https://drupal.org/project/views) that lists all of your team members (regardless the team for now).
3. In 'Contextual filters' under 'Advanced' settings of your view that you created in 2. add the field the you created in 1.
4. In the settings of that filter select 'Provide default value' and choose 'Content ID from URL'
5. Save your view.
6. Add [view field](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield) to your 'Our Team' content type, in the settings of that field select 'Always display default value' and below select the view that you created in 2.

As long as I understood you correctly this should do the trick.